# If print of an HTML template is more than 1 page, i want those pages merged in a single page

Tags: html, css

So i am using Freemarker and working on Report templates. Problem is it is expected to only have 1 page when printing, and if there are more than 1 page, other pages should be merged into 1 page like side by side. Can anyone help me with this ?

```
<table style="border:1px white; width:100%;border-collapse:collapse"> 
            <#list recordList as item>
            <tr >
              <td class="always" style="width:5%;">${(item.record)!}</td>
             </td>
            </tr>`enter code here`
                </#list>
            </table>
```

Following code snippet represents the part which makes print have more than 1 pages on some occasions, in case it helps i put it here.

Comment: Note that this is purely a CSS question; you can remove the [freemarker] tag. (FreeMarker has no way to tell how many rows fit to a page, it operates during an earlier phase.)

Comment: What do you mean with "merged into one page"? Anyway printing with CSS is very limited and I don't think there is any way for CSS to react to how many pages are to be printed. You may need to  look for a different solution, for example, generate a PDF on the server.